# Accessing creating window

Tags: javascript

I am writing an authentication system, where you can login using G+, Facebook, login/password, etc.

When you click on "Facebook", I open a new window:

```
window.open('/auth/' + self.action + '/facebook', '', 'width=800, height=600');
```

This will open the facebook auth window. When auth is over, however, I need the CREATING window (which at this point still has the login screen) to be redirected to the workspace (since you are now logged in!).

What's the best way of doing this? I guess either the parent window "polls" things (not even sure how), or the child window should somehow "tell" its parent that authentication was successful.

Any hints?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: window.opener should do the job: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the child window ends up on the same domain you can use [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener) to access properties of the opening `window`:

```
if (completedAuth) {
    window.opener.eventBus.trigger("user:auth:successful", user);
}
```

Comment: @Merc - I just picked a random name on window.  The idea here is that you have some eventing system that everything can hook into to publish events that multiple things may be interested in subscribing to.  You can replace it with a simple call to a function, i. e. `window.opener.userIsAuthorized();`